# Why are my drop-down lists not appearing below my navigation?

Tags: html, css, list

On the 'shop' tab I have 5 drop down options that link to a specific part of content on the shop page. However my code does not seem to work, as when you hover over the shop tab when on the home page, the navigation appears inline with the rest of the navigation, whereas I would like the content to display below the word shop as a drop-down list.

This is the HTML

```
<pre>
<div id="navigation"> 
<ul class="nav-bar">
<li><a href="index.html">home</a></li>
<li class="current"><a href="shop.html">shop</a>
<ul>
<li><a href="#vintage">Vintage Collection</a></li>
<li><a href="#sofas">Sofas & Beds</a></li>
<li><a href="#tables">Tables & Chairs</a></li>
<li><a href="#electricals">Electricals</a></li>
<li><a href="#storage">Storage</a></li>
</ul>
</li>
<li><a href="about.html">about</a></li>
<li><a href="getinvolved.html"> get involved </a></li>
<li><a href="contact.html"> contact us</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

</pre>
```

and this is the CSS

```
    /* drop down list */


#navigation ul ul {
    display: none;
    top: 100%;
    left:0;
    background:#A3CC39;
    padding: 0;
    align-content: center;
    width: 100%;
}

#navigation ul ul li {
    float: none;
    width: 100%;
    margin-left:0px;

}

#navigation ul ul a {
    line-height: 120%;
    padding: 10px 15px;
}

#navigation ul ul ul {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}

#navigation ul li:hover > ul {
    display: block;
}
```

I have a feeling the reason it isn't working is to do with my code at the very top of my css which styles the original navigation bar. Really appreciate any help

EDIT: this is rest of the css for the navigation as a whole:

```
* {
    margin:0;
    border:0;
    padding:0;

}

.wrapper {
    max-width: 1000px;
    margin: 0px auto;
    clear: both;
    text-align: center;
}

li {
    display: inline;
    list-style-type: none;

}

#navigation a:hover{
    color: black;
    background-color: #6A8F28;
}

#navigation a { 
    text-decoration: none; color:white; 
}

a:visited { 
    text-decoration: none; 
}
```

Comment: Is this really all of the css that you are using for the menu, because it seems that some of it is missing here. For instance, your menu is not inline, but each under another, etc.

Comment: i have now added the rest of the css

Comment: No worries, completed it! needed to add a display: inline-block to the #navigation ul li { attribute in css